Создание динамического многомерного массива с неопределенным уровнем вложенности
Создание динамического многомерного массива с неопределенным уровнем вложенности
Имеем массив

$array = [
    1 => [
        'a' => 'a1',
        'b' => 'b1',
        'c' => 'c1',
    ],
    2 => [
        'a' => 'a2',
        'b' => 'b2',
        'c' => 'c2',
    ],
    3 => [
        'a' => 'a3',
        'b' => 'b3',
        'c' => 'c3',
    ]
]

Необходимо сделать многомерный массив, исходя из разных условий:
При условии ['a','b'] сделать:
foreach ( $array as $item ) {
    $newArray[$item['a']][$item['b']] = $item;
}

При условии ['a','a'] сделать:
foreach ( $array as $item ) {
    $newArray[$item['a']][$item['a']] = $item;
}

При условии ['a','b','c'] сделать:
foreach ( $array as $item ) {
    $newArray[$item['a']][$item['b']][$item['c']] = $item;
}


Думаю, что это вам будет полезно
